# Represent a structure in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

I have a structure which contains an `int` value as key and a group of `datetime` as value.

My question is how to represent such a structure in C#?

I tried `Dictionary<int, DateTime[]>` but I can't work with the dictionary while adding and removing `datetime` elements, since the dictionary always requires a different array for each key, which is not practical to be programmed in my application.

Answer (score 5):

This data structure will work:

```
IDictionary<int,List<DateTime>> datesById = new Dictionary<int,List<DateTime>>();

datesById.Add(1, new List<DateTime>());
datesById[1].Add(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Containers in C# have corresponding methods to convert themselves into others

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.

Comment: I believe this is referring to, for example, the `.ToList()` methods and `List<T>`'s constructor which takes `IEnumerable<T>`.